# False file permission denied error when opening one specific word document on my Mac

Tags: mac, finder, ms-office, permission

There is one specific word doc that contains a draft SOP for running a piece of manufacturing equipment. When I select this file to open it from the Finder or from Word, I get a permission error, and "Select this file to give access to it". I select it, and then it raises the error: "User does not have permission to access this file."

Historically, I have had no problem opening this file. All the sudden, I get permission denied. I have tried selecting [CTRL] and [right click the file from Finder] and select [get info]. When I do, I get, as expected, I get: me: rwx, staff: r--, others: r--.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Press `cmd + space`, search for `terminal`, type `cd` and drag&drop the directory containing the file to it, press `enter`. Type `chmod 777 name_of_your_file.doc`, press `enter` again. See if it opens now.. if so, something was indeed wrong with your permissions.. Please let me know the result, it might not be dafe to leave the setting at `777` as this allowes everyone to have full rights regarding the file.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions look okay.  Maybe you're not (or are no longer) the owner.  Try opening Terminal.app  Then type: `chown USER ~/Desktop/FILE` replacing USER with your username, and FILE with the filename plus the extension, assuming it's on your Desktop.  If you've executed the command successfully, it will seem like nothing has happened.  If you fail, it will complain, but you're not going to harm anything.

Then try to open it.

Aside from that, I'd maybe you could have encrypted it by mistake?